# How can I check if the microphone is being used?

Tags: windows, windows-10, microphone

How can I check if the microphone is being used (Windows 10)? I would like to check this using a command line.

[There is a tray icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DO3AO.png) in the windows bar that says the microphone is in use.

However, I am writing my program that needs this information, so I would like to check this using the console.

Comment: You are not going to be able to do this within bash (command prompt).  You might be able to check device status within PowerShell.  Something like [this](https://github.com/frgnca/AudioDeviceCmdlets) would give you a start to developing something yourself. [This](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/weekend-scripter-use-powershell-to-find-and-disable-webcams/) requires Devcon to mange but also provide some insight into how this could be acomplished.

Comment: Thank you! However, I looked at AudioDeviceCmdlets and I cannot see a function in the API that checks if a microphone is currently being used

Comment: You would have to write it.  I indicate that would be the case in my original comment, but it's a start, stand by statement you won't be able to do this within a command prompt.  You will be unable to utilize WDK within a command prompt, and WDK at the very least, will be required for something like this.

Comment: @Patres: did you come up with a command line solution?